# Знаки препинания в, казалось бы, наипростейших примерах?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Два друга Равшан и Джамшут приехали в Москву на заработки.
2. Два друга, Равшан и Джамшут, приехали в Москву на заработки.
3. Два друга - Равшан и Джамшут - приехали в Москву на заработки.
4. Два друга: Равшан и Джамшут приехали в Москву на заработки.

Следуя разным правилам, получается, что все варианты допустимы ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктуация в предложениях верна, кроме последнего. Не понятно,на основании какого правила Вы поставили двоеточие.

***Дополнение:***

Т.к. это мужские имена, то в первое предложение надо внести исправление: Дмамшута и Равшана. Если бы это были женские имена, то несклоняемый вариант был бы правильный. Несклоняемый вариант без запятых - неправильный.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Серж, за ответы! Возможно я и не прав совсем , но,  я думаю, нет и такого правила, которое  запретило бы мне поставить двоеточие в примере №4.

Comment: В ваших примерах - простое предложение. Оснований для двоеточий нет.

Comment: Угрюм, скажите, Джамшут - женское имя тоже есть?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Два друга Равшан и Джамшут приехали в Москву на заработки.
>
> Два друга, Равшан и Джамшут, приехали в Москву на заработки.
> ```

Пунктуация-то верна, только смысл у предложений разный.

Во втором предложении приведены имена приехавших в Москву людей (Равшан и Джамшут),

тогда как в первом -- имена людей (Равшан и Джамшут), друзья которых приехали в Москву.

Comment: Слава, а почему вы считаете, что в первом примере Равшан и Дмамшут стоят в родительном падеже?

Answer (score 0):

1) Два друга Равшан и Джамшут приехали в Москву на заработки **(под вопросом).**

2) Два друга, Равшан и Джамшут, приехали в Москву на заработки (обособление приложения со значением уточнения с помощь запятых). Это схема применяется чаще всего.

Два друга - Равшан и Джамшут - приехали в Москву на заработки (обособление приложения со значением уточнения с помощь тире). В этой схеме  ряд обозначает дополнительные сведения, вынесен на второй план, интонация исключения.

Два друга: Равшан и Джамшут - приехали в Москву на заработки (два друга - обобщающее слово). Фактически эта схема не применяется для двучленного ряда с союзом И.

Пояснение

1) Здесь можно ориентироваться на разные правила: (а) обособление приложений и (б) обособление однородного ряда при наличии обобщающего слова.

2) Если приложение выражено счетным оборотом, то обычно используется обособление ряда запятыми (двучленный ряд, союза И)  или  тире (в других случаях).

3) Вариант без обособления "Два друга Равшан и Джамшут" несколько сомнителен: необособленные приложения не так часто встречаются, а здесь мы имеем дело  с  однородным рядом, а не  с одиночным приложением.

Примеры

И обе старшие девочки, Катя и Соня, стали зорко следить за мальчиками.

Только нам троим: отцу, мне и Евсеичу – не было скучно.

В четырёх городах Италии – Риме, Милане, Неаполе и Турине – начались финальные игры по футболу.